# How can I display an element to the left and other to the center using flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to accomplish something like the image, but without the third element, having one element fixed on the left and another in the center.

[image]

Is there an easier way without flexbox?

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
  <button>Left Header</button>
  <button>middle</button>
</div>
```

Comment: either put a dummy box in place of third box or just make the whole container's width 50%, then flex space-between on it.

Comment: if the parent container had 50% width the second element wouldn't be exactly in the middle

Comment: Please add your html and css. It will be easier to solve the issue.

Comment: @iamentafaz added a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im sure there is a better way, but how about just hiding last column?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  /* no important; just to visualize*/
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.item.last { /* :last-child doesn't work */
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item last">C</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `postion` for first `div` and `margin` for the second `div`, like this

```css
.container {
  postion: relative;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: teal;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.item.one {
  position: absolute;
}

.item.two {
  margin: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item one">A</div>
  <div class="item two">B</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this code

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
  <button>Left Header</button>
  <button style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto">middle</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use flexbox "self-align".

Just check it [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-self/).

Comment: This only works if `flex-direction` is set to `column`, which results in the items not being displayed in the same row.